# Not being able to deploy ECS Service - Deployment Failed

Tags: docker, nginx, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

At a conceptual level, I understand Docker & Kubernetes. I am trying out some things on AWS ECS, but these are not working for me.

I have been trying to create and deploy an ECS service based on the docker hub image nginexdemos/hello (uri).

I have created a cluster, a task definition based on the image, an application load balancer,and a service. When I try to deploy the service, I get an error. Shown Below

[image: Error in ECS Service Console]

When I try to run the service using the loadbalancer dns I get the following error (503
[image]

This should be a pretty straightforward exercise. But obviously, there is something wrong somewhere.

Just to mention that I am able to use the image successfully to create a container using Docker Desktop.

But in AWS, the service itself is not being deployed

Any suggestions that cna lead me in the right direction would be most welcome.

Regards
Nomad

Comment: What do the events say for this `Service`? also you might want to verify the health checks for the target groups associated with the LB

Comment: You need to look at the container's logs to see if there is an error on startup. And you need to verify that the target group is sending traffic to the correct port that the container is listening on.

Comment: I have the same problem. Since the deployment fails, there are no logs from the containers as they never get started. There are also no logs from AWS which indicate what the failure is. The 503 is because there is no container running.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the task details and the task log to see what's going wrong.
Here's some typical deployment problems:

- Task deployment failed due to connectivity problem to the registry. It happens if you're deploying the container in a private subnet, and you don't have a NAT Gateway (or an Interface Enpoint, if your container image is stored on ECR)
- Missing IAM permissions, in the container execution role, to interact with some service you use in your container logic.
- Failed healtchecks, if you're deploying in a target group associated to an ALB.

Comment: H, Thanks for your reply. There is no private subnet. It is a regular deployment across the various subnets in a VPC in a region (lets say US-East-1). There is no IM role required, as the only thing the image is doing is displaying a simple page of nginx webserver with info such as hostname, ip address and port)

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem and it was not clear at all what could be going wrong. I have tried enabling cloudwatch logs on my ECS, but they were not logging anything (I think that the reason why there were no logs from the container, was that the container simply could not start. There were also no logs from ECS, because the deployment failed every time).

In my case, I am using an Azure DevOps pipeline to build my application, create a Docker image and push it to my ECR. This pipeline produces an artifact, which I can then use in the 'Releases' section of Azure DevOps. I have figured out that there is an option of adding an AWS shell script:
[add AWS shell script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ae4rk.png) in that same part of Azure DevOps (Releases).

Once you select the AWS shell script option, you can configure it to use your AWS credentials (Access Key ID, Secret Access Key, AWS Region). You can then write a shell script that lets you update the task definition with the new Docker image and push it to the ECS service (with the updated task definition). Here's the AWS Shell Script that lets you achieve this:

```
# Retrieve the existing task definition
EXISTING_TASK_DEFINITION=$( aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition $(taskDefinitionFamily) )

# Replace the Docker image with the new one
NEW_TASK_DEFINITION=$( echo "$EXISTING_TASK_DEFINITION" | jq --arg newImage "$(newDockerImageDev)" '{family: .taskDefinition.family, taskRoleArn: .taskDefinition.taskRoleArn, executionRoleArn: .taskDefinition.executionRoleArn, networkMode: .taskDefinition.networkMode, containerDefinitions: .taskDefinition.containerDefinitions, volumes: .taskDefinition.volumes, placementConstraints: .taskDefinition.placementConstraints, requiresCompatibilities: .taskDefinition.requiresCompatibilities, cpu: .taskDefinition.cpu, memory: .taskDefinition.memory, runtimePlatform: .taskDefinition.runtimePlatform} | .containerDefinitions[0].image = $newImage' )

# Save the updated task definition to a file
echo "$NEW_TASK_DEFINITION" > updated-task-definition.json

# Register the updated task definition
TASK_DEFINITION_OUTPUT=$( aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file://updated-task-definition.json )
echo "Task Definition Output: $TASK_DEFINITION_OUTPUT"

FAMILY_NAME=$( echo "$TASK_DEFINITION_OUTPUT" | jq -r '.taskDefinition.family' )
echo "Family Name: $FAMILY_NAME"

# Update the ECS service with the new task definition
aws ecs update-service --cluster $(ecsClusterName) --service $(ecsServiceName) --task-definition $FAMILY_NAME --force-new-deployment
```

One thing worth noting is that I have explained my specific scenario that uses Azure DevOps (specifically the 'pipelines' and 'releases' sections of Azure DevOps). However, this shell script uses standard AWS CLI commands to retrieve the existing task defition, replace the Docker image, update the task defition and update the ECS service with the new task definition, which I believe are the steps that OP is missing to have a successful ECS deployment (it's possible that some of those commands may need to be slightly tweaked for OP's use case). I hope this helps!